# R: Collect igraph nodes adjacent to selected nodes in a list

Tags: r, graph, igraph, adjacency-list

Define the toy graph as:

```
> library(igraph)
> g = graph( c("John", "Jim",
               "Jim", "Jill", 
               "Jill", "John",
               "Jim", "Bob",
               "Bob", "Alice", 
               "Alice", "Jill"),
            directed=FALSE)
```

Select 2 nodes randomly as:

```
> select = V(g)[sample(1:5,2)]
> select
+ 2/5 vertices, named, from b165a23:
[1] John Jim
```

Determine nodes immediately adjacent to the 2 above selected nodes in graph:

```
> adj = adjacent_vertices(g,select,mode="all")
> adj
$John
+ 2/5 vertices, named, from b165a23:
[1] Jim  Jill
$Jim
+ 3/5 vertices, named, from b165a23:
[1] John Jill Bob
```

What I get is a list `adj` made of 2 lists: `adj$John` and `adj$Jim`. 
 
What I want is to collect all nodes adjacent to John and Jim, that is:
Jim, Jill, John, Jill and Bob
then put them in a single list. Jill is repeated intentionally because I am actually interested in counting edge stubs.

I did try various ways,e.g.:

```
sel_list=adj$John
for  (ii = 2:(length(adj)) {
  sel_list = append(sel_list,adj[[ii]]) 
}
```

or

```
sel_list = c()
for  (ii = 1:(length(adj)) {
  sel_list = c(sel_list,adj[[ii]]) 
}
```

The above does give me a list of vertices, but only captures the first component of the lists `adj[[ii]]`. For large problems, I need a way to collect all adjacent vertices without resorting to yet another expensive `for` loops to capture all elements of `adj[[ii]]`, such as the ugly hack:

```
sel_list = c()
for  (ii = 1:(length(adj)) {
  int_list=c()
  for (kk in 1:length(adj[[ii]]) {
    int_list=c(int_list,adj[[ii]][kk])
  }
  sel_list = c(sel_list,int_list) 
}
```

which, for a reason I don't understand, does not capture all nodes in `adj[[ii]]` as I expected.

What is the best way to go about selecting all adjacent nodes to a set of other nodes and put them in a simple list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just `unlist(adj)` and use that to index into `V(g)`
I will repeat some code from the question and set the random seed to make the result repeatable,

```
set.seed(26)
select = V(g)[sample(1:5,2)]
select
+ 2/5 vertices, named, from e2f7066:
[1] John Jim 

adj = adjacent_vertices(g,select,mode="all")
N = unlist(adj)
V(g)[N]
+ 5/5 vertices, named, from e2f7066:
[1] Jim  Jill John Jill Bob
```

Comment: g3 -> g :  Good catch ! Just a typo. Corrected.

Comment: From what I see playing around, this only permits the recovery of the first node of each adjacency list in `adj`. In this case I only get to put Jim and John in a list of neighboring vertices. Jill and Bob fall out.... I did implement `unlist` with `recursive =TRUE`, which is default anyway. It does not change that behavior. To check do `is.element("Jill", V(g)[unlist(adj)]). Am I missing something basic ?

Comment: The code works for me.  Your test `is.element("Jill", V(g)[unlist(adj)])` does fail, but that is because you cannot test this way. Try `is.element("Jill", V(g))`  It also returns false.  If you look at `unclass(V(g)[N])` you will see that `V(g)[N]` is a _named list_ of node _numbers_. You need to test like this  `is.element(3, V(g)[N])`

Comment: Yes ! I have been struggling with named list for hours now, trying to make sense of the bizarre naming "convention" when nodes (as in my real case) have labels that are in fact numerals.  In the present case "Jill" is the third node. So one tests based on node's sequence number.   I accept your answer because you definitely nailed it. Tks ! But is there a way to test whether a node is in the igraph.vs  based on label ?  This would be handy and perhaps more natural ... (Maybe another post to answer that question ?)

Comment: I can just answer it here. Instead of `is.element("Jill", V(g)[N])`  use `is.element(V(g)["Jill"], V(g)[N])`